# How to delete row after checking if it exists/doesn't exist from the same table?

Tags: javascript, php, sqlite

How to delete row after checking if it exists/doesn't exist from the same table?

How to check if the rowID exist on the same table and if exists then delete it otherwise it should not complain.

```
delete from Mistake_Table where exists(select id from Mistake where id=3);
```

It's not working, it's deleting everything!

Comment: Is `from the same table` true? Your query is running on 2 tables..

Comment: From the same table

Comment: I made wrong query for sure.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your query deletes all rows is that if **any** row exists with `id = 3`, the `EXISTS` expression is true for **all** rows, hence they all get deleted.

To solve your problem, you can simply write

```
DELETE FROM Mistake_Table WHERE id=3
```

and it will only delete a row with `id = 3` if one exists.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please say, 
how to check if the rowID exist on the same table and if exists then delete it otherwise it should not complain.

Comment: @bisalsarker the `WHERE` clause on the delete checks to see if a row with `id = 3` exists and deletes it if it does. If there is no row with `id = 3` the delete query will still succeed even though it won't delete anything.